# How to install files to the Mydocuments folder using Set up project in vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I need to install the some files under the mydocuments of logged in user. How can i specify the install directory in the set up project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the **File System** view of your installer project, right click on File System  and select Add Special Folder -> **User's Personal Data Folder**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2esdf4x.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1